# Instagram GET media search error

Tags: jquery, python, instagram, media, instagram-api

Im trying to create a query to collect all images from instagram api with refference to media search.Here is my code in Python

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
api = InstagramAPI(access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN')
result, __pagination_url = api.media_search(q="query", count=20, lat=54.1, lng="35.2", min_timestamp="2013-03-01 15:28:02", max_timestamp ="2013-04-01 15:28:02")
```

However i keep on receiving this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this , ive tried to solve this issue but no results yet, also i want to print out all the links that the data retrieves.

Thank you

Comment: Run `print api.media_search(q="query", count=20, lat=54.1, lng="35.2", min_timestamp="2013-03-01 15:28:02", max_timestamp ="2013-04-01 15:28:02")` and you will see the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The query returns one value, so use this:

```
result = api.media_search(q="query", count=20, lat=54.1, lng="35.2", min_timestamp="2013-03-01 15:28:02", max_timestamp ="2013-04-01 15:28:02")
```

Your code tried to take two and failed.